# how can i convert an image to YCbCr considering a range with negative values?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, colors, color-space

in matlab there is a function rgb2ycbcr, this function uses several ranges depending on the input image representation, but all these range consider positive values.
Instead i wish to represent my values as in this plot

[image: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YCbCr#mediaviewer/File:YCbCr-CbCr_Scaled_Y50.png]

how can i?

Comment: Can't you just multiply by 2 and then subtract 1?  (Or whatever factors are necessary, depending on your initial range.)

Answer (score 0):

You can map the output from `rgb2ycbcr` to the -1 to +1 range.  For example, one of the possible ranges for Cb and Cr output from `rgb2ycbcr` is [16 240], which can be remapped easily using `interp1`.  Cb in the code below represents the Cb column in the output matrix from `rgb2ycbcr`; you may need to do some reshape operation.

```
CbNew = interp1([16, 240], [-1, 1], Cb);
```

You could also automatically find the appropriate remapping given the output data, since the three potential ranges are mutually exclusive.  The same remapping applies to Cr as well.

```
if any(Cb < 1)
    CbRange = [16/255, 240/255];

elseif any(Cb < 250)
    CbRange = [16, 240];

elseif any(Cb < 61681)
    CbRange = [4112, 61680];
else
    %\\suggest throwing an error here, since the above should cover all possible output
end

CbNew = interp1(CbRange, [-1, 1], Cb);
```